# Radio Button List Hangs Application in Angular 10

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 10 and was developing a simple template driven form by dynamically adding list of radio buttons. The code compiles successfully but when the application launch in browser it continuously loading and show the following error in FireFox:

"A web page is slowing down your browser. What would you like to do? [Stop it] [Wait]

I am attaching the source code and angular details:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="courseList">Course List</label>
    <select
      required
      ngModel
      name="courseList"
      #courseList="ngModel"
      id="courseList"
      class="form-control"
    >
      <option value=""> ----Please select ----</option>
      <option *ngFor="let course of getCourses()" [value]="course.Id">
        {{ course.Name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Experience</label>
    <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let level of getLevels()">
      <input ngModel type="radio" [value]="level.Id" name="contactMethod" />
      {{ level.Name }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <p>{{ f.value | json }}</p>
</form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css'],
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getCourses() {
    return [
      { Id: '1', Name: 'Course-A' },
      { Id: '2', Name: 'Course-B' },
      { Id: '3', Name: 'Course-C' },
    ];
  }

  getLevels() {
    return [
      { Id: '1', Name: 'Beginner' },
      { Id: '2', Name: 'Intermediate' },
      { Id: '3', Name: 'Expert' },
    ];
  }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone helps how to show the radio buttons? Thanks

Comment: Show your component..

Comment: @MikeOne component code is added. Please review it.

Comment: @user1770517 did you manage to solve this issue? Am facing the same problem.